# Make some elements not selectable jquery ui

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectable

i have some `td`s in a `table.`
all tds are `selectable`.

```
 <table id="selectable">
                              <tr>
                              <td class="ui-state-default" ></td>
                              <td class="ui-state-default" ></td>
                              <td class="ui-state-default" ></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                              <td class="ui-state-default" ></td>
                              <td class="ui-state-default" ></td>
                              <td class="ui-state-default" ></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                              <td class="ui-state-default" ></td>
                              <td class="ui-state-default" ></td>
                              <td class="ui-state-default" ></td>
                              </tr>                             
                            </table>
```

i want some `td`s as not selectable. how to make it.please help

Comment: Add a class on the non-selectable elements then capture that in an event that cancels whatever you dont want to happen

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fiddle example using an event that would change the cell color to black http://jsfiddle.net/mpw0tkjL/

```
$( "#selectable td" ).on( "click", changeColor );

function changeColor( e ){
    var $el = $( e.currentTarget );

    if( !$el.hasClass( "not-selectable" ) ){
        $( e.currentTarget ).css( "background", "black" );
    } else {
        alert( "dont change color" );
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: i found another simple solution.

Comment: Can you edit your post with your simpler solution then?

Answer (score 1):

As  [Scott Mitchell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1212386/scott-mitchell) said  Added a class `not-selectable` on the non-selectable elements.

```
var $el = $(".not-selectable");
        //alert($el.length);
         if($el.length >0 ){
            //Cannot select when there are class not-selectable
            return false;
        }
```

**update**

**i found exact way**

```
$(function () {
   $("#selectable").selectable({
      cancel: "td.not-selectable"   
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <style>

        .not-selectable {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

    </style>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

 });  
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <table id="selectable">
        <tr>
        <td class="ui-state-default" >11</td>
        <td class="ui-state-default" >222</td>
        <td class="not-selectable" >33</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="ui-state-default" >44</td>
        <td class="not-selectable" >44</td>
        <td class="ui-state-default" >44</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="ui-state-default" >55</td>
        <td class="ui-state-default" >55</td>
        <td class="ui-state-default" >22</td>
        </tr>                             
    </table>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions work, but with the second solution, it cancels all the event propagation.What I mean by that is I had a checkbox in a .not-selectable `<td>` and it was not getting checked at all how many every times I click. Once I replaces the updated solution with var $el= code snippet, it started getting checked again. Thought it would help someone.

```
var $el = $(".not-selectable");
        //alert($el.length);
         if($el.length >0 ){
            //Cannot select when there are class not-selectable
            return false;
        }
update

i found exact way

$(function () {
   $("#selectable").selectable({
      cancel: "td.not-selectable"   
   });
});
```